# Deleting last row in table of protected sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a proposal budget development sheet for the faculty to use on our campus. The spreadsheet contains many formulas and functions properly to calculate salaries and fringe, which have been protected so that the faculty cannot adjust the calculations.

The first problem I ran into was allowing the end users to enter/delete rows with the cells protected and have the formulas auto-populate, so I made each section of the budget into a table.

To get around the protection aspect, I found code for a macro on a forum that allowed the sheet to be unprotected, insert a row at the end of the table, and reprotect it. This is the code:

```
Sub AddRowEquipment()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Range("A44").End(xlDown).ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=False
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:="password"
End Sub
```

I would simply like to have assistance creating a code that does the reverse, unprotects the sheet, deletes the last row of the identified table, and reprotects it.

Comment: You found code that works and you want to do the opposite and have asked `many people in IT` but no one has been able to figure it out O.o

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I am assuming your table starts on cell A44 like the picture below.
[image]

```
Sub DeleteRowEquipment()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A44").listobject.Range.Rows.Count
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
Range("A44").listobject.ListRows(lastrow-1).Delete
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:="password"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lydia If this was what you are looking for do not forget to accept this as answer and to give me an upvote.

Comment: It did not work. Gave me the following error: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: @Lydia When you hit debug, what line is highlighted?  I changed one row in my code.

Comment: @Lydia, if my response was the answer to your question please accept it as the answer.

Comment: It initially was; however, after testing the sheet, I determined that the tables could not be referenced ranges. As rows were added to prior sections, the range in the subsequent macros stayed the same, causing rows to be added to incorrect sections. I changed the macro to reflect a table.Still having trouble with the reverse.

    `Sub AddRowKeyPersonnel()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:="password"
    End Sub`